# How to solve a Pandas Merge Error: key must be integer or timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge to pandas dataframes, one is called DAILY and the other SF1.

DAILY csv:

```
ticker,date,lastupdated,ev,evebit,evebitda,marketcap,pb,pe,ps
A,2020-09-14,2020-09-14,31617.1,36.3,26.8,30652.1,6.2,44.4,5.9
```

SF1 csv (not sure why ticker is indented, just ignore that):

```
    ticker,dimension,calendardate,datekey,reportperiod,lastupdated,accoci,assets,assetsavg,assetsc,assetsnc,assetturnover,bvps,capex,cashneq,cashnequsd,cor,consolinc,currentratio,de,debt,debtc,debtnc,debtusd,deferredrev,depamor,deposits,divyield,dps,ebit,ebitda,ebitdamargin,ebitdausd,ebitusd,ebt,eps,epsdil,epsusd,equity,equityavg,equityusd,ev,evebit,evebitda,fcf,fcfps,fxusd,gp,grossmargin,intangibles,intexp,invcap,invcapavg,inventory,investments,investmentsc,investmentsnc,liabilities,liabilitiesc,liabilitiesnc,marketcap,ncf,ncfbus,ncfcommon,ncfdebt,ncfdiv,ncff,ncfi,ncfinv,ncfo,ncfx,netinc,netinccmn,netinccmnusd,netincdis,netincnci,netmargin,opex,opinc,payables,payoutratio,pb,pe,pe1,ppnenet,prefdivis,price,ps,ps1,receivables,retearn,revenue,revenueusd,rnd,roa,roe,roic,ros,sbcomp,sgna,sharefactor,sharesbas,shareswa,shareswadil,sps,tangibles,taxassets,taxexp,taxliabilities,tbvps,workingcapital
A,ARQ,2020-09-14,2020-09-14,2020-09-14,2020-09-14,53000000,7107000000,,4982000000,2125000000,,10.219,-30000000,1368000000,1368000000,1160000000,131000000,2.41,0.584,665000000,111000000,554000000,665000000,281000000,96000000,0,0.0,0.0,202000000,298000000,0.133,298000000,202000000,202000000,0.3,0.3,0.3,4486000000,,4486000000,50960600000,,,354000000,0.806,1.0,1086000000,0.484,0,0,4337000000,,1567000000,42000000,42000000,0,2621000000,2067000000,554000000,51663600000,1368000000,-160000000,2068000000,111000000,0,1192000000,-208000000,-42000000,384000000,0,131000000,131000000,131000000,0,0,0.058,915000000,171000000,635000000,0.0,11.517,,,1408000000,0,114.3,,,1445000000,131000000,2246000000,2246000000,290000000,,,,,0,625000000,1.0,452000000,439000000,440000000,5.116,7107000000,0,71000000,113000000,16.189,2915000000
```

Datasorting/cleaning code:

```
sf1 = sf1.drop(columns=['number','dimension', 'datekey', 'reportperiod','lastupdated', 'ev', 'evebit', 'evebitda', 'marketcap', 'pb', 'pe', 'ps'])

daily = daily.sort_values('date', ascending=True)
sf1 = sf1.sort_values('calendardate', ascending=True)
daily = daily.sort_values('ticker')
sf1 = sf1.sort_values('ticker')
```

Code to merge the dataframes:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(daily, sf1, by = 'ticker', left_on='date', right_on='calendardate', tolerance=pd.Timedelta(value=100, unit='D'), direction='backward')
```

I think what may be causing the error is that the dataframes are being merged by the ticker column. I'm not sure if that has to be an int or in a dateformat, or any specific format. Currently it is just the ticker of companies like shown above.

The dataframes are being merged on the date column in the DAILY csv and the calendardate column in the SF1 csv.

If someone could also make the distinction between what happens when merging `by` and how that changes if you were to only have `left_on` and `right_on`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this problem because your `date` column in ***'daily'*** and `calendardate` column in ***'sf1'*** are of type `object` i.e `string`

Just change their type to `datatime` by `pd.to_datetime()` method

so just add these 2 lines of code in your **Datasorting/cleaning code**:-

```
daily['date']=pd.to_datetime(daily['date'])
sf1['calendardate']=pd.to_datetime(sf1['calendardate'])
```

Now write:-

```
df = pd.merge_asof(daily, sf1, by = 'ticker', left_on='date', right_on='calendardate', tolerance=pd.Timedelta(value=100, unit='D'), direction='backward')
```